# node readFileSync with a c like char buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's some sample code. I have files (local machine) that can be 1+GB and I want to process it. However my code is a bit slow and ugly.

For example below I wrote `buf[i] == 10` to find the first newline. In C I can write `== '\n'` which is clear enough. However `'\n'` is a string in JS and I can't write this?

Is it possible I can make code more clear? I also need to check for commas and do a C like strcmp. Can I make this clear without making copies?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Buffer } = require('node:buffer');
let buf = Buffer.alloc(4096);
let fd = fs.openSync("large.file");
let rdlen = fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, 4096, 0);
let end = -1;
for(let i=0; i<rdlen; i++) {
    if (buf[i] == 10) {
        end = i;
        break;
    }
}

console.log("Fist newline is at " + end)
```

Comment: `== '\n'.charCodeAt(0)`?

Comment: Though to answer the more general question: no, you should not write JavaScript code as if it was C code. It'll be weird, unidiomatic, and slower - if you want C, use C.

Comment: I agree, I after looking at the question more closely this seems more like a task suited for C. Is there a reason you need to write this in Javascript?

Comment: All the other code is in JS so I wanted to be consistent. But I think this could be better in C. I tried a loop doing `buf[i] == 10` on every char and it took 3+seconds on my machine which isn't too bad but its half a second in C. So I guess C if my boss isn't oppose to it

Comment: Note that, in most cases, Javascript is just not a good language for processing a large buffer in a memory efficient way because anything other than brute force comparisons in the buffer will create duplicates of at least portions of the buffer.  Plus, you have no control over when those duplicates get freed.  This is precisely what C or Rust are good at as you directly control the things you really need to control in order to code this in a memory efficient way.

Comment: Also, Javascript does not give you a good set of comparison/search functions for buffers like you have in C or Rust.  Those functions exist for strings, but any manipulations of strings in Javascript (other than just reading them) involve making copies of data and then relying on garbage collection to not get excess memory buildup.

Comment: @AndrewSpar I doubt that a loop over a 4096 byte buffer will take 3s. What were you measuring?

Comment: @Bergi doing it in C. I measured a 4K buffer processing a 1.5GB file which is a real file I need to handle. I was hoping if its just one buffer and small I'd have good speed and no collection but it's just slow and C does it in <500ms

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `Buffer` to a UTF-8 encoded string, and use the `indexOf` function:

```
// ...
let fd = fs.openSync("large.file");
let rdlen = fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, 4096, 0);
console.log("First newline is at " + buf.toString().indexOf('\n'));
```

`indexOf` will get the first instance of a character in the string. If the character isn't found, it'll return `-1`, which is exactly what your code does.

I *think* this should work on non-UTF8 files, too.

Comment: OP asked for a method "*without making copies*"

Comment: I guess my example is bad. I specifically need to loop and look at each char because in the body I want to check for ',', '\n' AND if its a special keyword but I only check the keywords after the comma